# Segmentation Fault error using fgets function in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I am writing a small code in C for copying specific string from a text file into another text file. The string is in the middle somewhere. 
I wrote a code in C. When I compiled, I was getting a segmentation fault error.

Please help. My code is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fptr1, *fptr2;
    char c;
    char data[100];

    // Open one file for reading
    fptr1 = fopen(SPATH, "r");
    if (fptr1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", SPATH);
        exit(0);
    }

    // Open another file for writing
    fptr2 = fopen(DPATH, "w");
    if (fptr2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", DPATH);
        exit(0);
    }

    // Read contents from file
    while (!feof(fptr1))
    {
        fgets(data[20],29,fptr1);
        printf("\n %s",data[20]);
        fputs(data[29], fptr2);
    }   

    printf("\nContents copied to %s", "file2.txt");

    fclose(fptr1);
    fclose(fptr2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `data[20]` is a single `char`, and `fgets(data[20], 29, fptr1)` causes its value to be used as if it is the address of (the first character of) a buffer of 29 characters.   That is undefined behaviour.     Change the usage to either `fgets(data, 29, fptr1)` (to specify a buffer length of 29 starting with the first character of `data`) or `fgets(&data[20], 29, fptr1)` (to specify a buffer of 29 starting with the 21st character of `data`).      Also change the `printf()` call in the same way, since it also has undefined behaviour for the same reason.

Comment: You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Answer (score 1):

[while ( !feof (file) ) is always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong), because `feof(file)` does not test `true` until `EOF` is encountered. If you are controlling your loop with:

```
while ( !feof (file) ) {
    /* read statement  */
    /* write statement */
}
```

Your read statement will read the last line (or character) in the file, leaving the next read to trigger `EOF`, however, the current read succeeded and did not set `EOF`, your write completes OK.

**What happens next?**

You test `feof (file)` which is still `false`, so `!feof (file)` tests `true` and you start processing the statements within the loop again. Your read **fails** because the read pointer was sitting right before `EOF`, you have an invalid read, then you then call your write statement invoking **Undefined Behavior** by writing an indeterminate value to your file. One you trigger *Undefined Behavior*, your program can do anything from appearing to complete successfully or SEGFAULT or anything in between.

Instead, simply control your read loop with `fgets` itself. That way, only if `fgets` succeeds will you enter your loop and write values to your file, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC  100           /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define DPATH "file2.txt"

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *fptr1 = NULL,     /* initialize all variables (good practice) */
         *fptr2 = NULL;
    char data[MAXC] = "";

    /* open/validate file for reading (default stdin) */
    fptr1 = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    if (fptr1 == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* open/validate file for writing */
    fptr2 = fopen (DPATH, "w");
    if (fptr2 == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", DPATH);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read contents from file */
    while (fgets (data, sizeof data, fptr1)) {  /* read 99-char blocks */
        printf ("%s", data);    /* (optional) output to stdout */
        fputs (data, fptr2);    /* write block to fptr2 */
    }

    printf ("\nContents copied to %s\n", DPATH);

    fclose(fptr1);
    if (fclose(fptr2) == EOF)   /* always validate close-after-write */
        perror ("fclose-fptr2");

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** don't use *magic numbers* or hardcoded values in your code, instead, if you need constants `#define` them (or for numeric constants you can also use a global `enum` to define them).

*Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

Check if output file exists:

```
$ ls -al file2.txt
ls: cannot access 'file2.txt': No such file or directory
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_copy_file <dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.

Contents copied to file2.txt
```

Check `file2.txt`:

```
$ cat file2.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other person to answer said, the definition of `fgets` is:

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

`data` is of type `char*`, so `data[whatever]` is of type `char`. That's no good. You should change that to just `data`. There are a few other places you do this. Change them to `data` as well.

To figure out that the problem was during the fgets, you could have used a debugger like GDB:

```
$ gcc foo.c -g -o myprogram // Compile your program. '-g' means to use debug, and '-o myprogram' is the name of the program you want to make.

// LOTS of warnings that you should have read, which tell you you're probably using 'data' wrong

$ gdb myprogram
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40074e: file foo.c, line 7.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/anthonyd973/Desktop/myprogram

Breakpoint 1, main () at foo.c:7
7       {
(gdb) next
13      fptr1 = fopen(SPATH, "r");
(gdb) next
14      if (fptr1 == NULL)
(gdb) next
23      fptr2 = fopen(DPATH, "w");
(gdb) next
24      if (fptr2 == NULL)
(gdb) next
33      while (!feof(fptr1))
(gdb) next
35      fgets(data[20],29,fptr1);
(gdb) next

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. // So the problem is at line 35, during 'fgets'.
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

        Inferior 1 [process 17669] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y

$
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `while` loop as follows:

```
while (!feof(fptr1))
{

    fgets(data, 99, fptr1);

    fputs(data, fptr2);

}
```

Please read the document about fgets(), fputs(). Just type `man fgets`, `man fputs`.

Comment: Modify your `while` loop as follows: `while (fgets(data, sizeof data, fptr1)) fputs (data, fptr2);` (see: [Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that problem. Use `while(fgets(data, 99, fptr1) != NULL)` instead.

Comment: If `data` is defined `char[100]` then passing `100` to `fgets()` is perfectly fine, as it is aware of taking the `0` terminator in to account.